# In PDF(Using XAML) how to continue the overflow items in the next page?

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

I'm Creating a PDF using XAML my problem is I have insufficient space for my list and need to continue it for the next page. How will I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, you could refer to the [`Printing`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) official code sample.

And **scenario 4** demonstrates print a range of pages with a custom print template.

You could also refer to [`Print from your app`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app) official document to learn more about UWP printing.